# Button not shown in Mozilla Firefox & Internet Explorer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, browser, cross-browser

I have use a Button with following CSS:

```
<button type="button" id="SaveDocument" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: -82.6%; margin-top: -7%; width: 113px; position:fixed;" data-loading-text=" saving..."> Save</button>
```

and this Button is Seen in Google Chrome 
But its not displayed in Mozilla FireFox & Internet Explorer

Please Help me on this ASAP.

Comment: Could you provide more context please? a fiddle would be great. When I paste your HTML in jsfiddle the button would not show because if the negative margins. I would start by removing that and see if it helps.

Comment: Well id doesn't work because your `position` is fixed and you have a negative `top` and `left` margin. How it works in Firefox and IE is the real question!

Comment: I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem... why is your position is fixed with a negative top and left margin? I strongly encourage you to follow @myajouri's advice and create a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You're displaying the button out of the screen when using these margin values.

Try to set positive values.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="SaveDocument" style="width: 113px; margin-top: 7%; margin-left: 82.6%; position: fixed;" type="button" data-loading-text=" saving..."> Save</button>
```

[**DEMO**](http://bootply.com/98454)